# What amount is needed to construct the World Congress projects?

Tags: civilization-5, civilization-5-brave-new-world

Does anyone know the total amount needed for each project?  This would help in determining not to over allocate to these projects.

Example: If world's fair needed 6000 points, then I know 
3001 (>50%) gets me first place
2000 (>33%) can get me first but guarantees 2nd

In the case of World's fair I may want 2nd, one free social policy right away, especially if my culture is low, because of 100% of pathetic is pathetic.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The amount of total production needed for each project to be complete, as well as the amounts needed for Silver/Bronze, can vary. The basic rule is as follows:

- Each project has a base production amount. 350 for World's Fair, 720 for International Games, 850 for International Space Station. This is modified, as all production amounts are, by game speed.
- Building a project takes (gamespeed-modified base production) * (total number of civilizations) production. So, in a two-civ match, the World's Fair will only take 700 hammers, total. In a 16-civ match, it will take a total of 5600.
- The gamespeed-modified base production is the amount a civ needs to get silver, half that much is the amount needed to get bronze. This has the consequence that in a two-civ match, unless each civ contributes the exact same amount, the one who does not contribute the most will basically be unable to get the silver reward.

Comment: This is a good answer, one question: point 2 is it the total number of civs or the total number of civs still alive?

Comment: The game is unclear, and I haven't personally run into that situation yet; if I find out before anyone else can bring it up, I'll edit it into the answer.

Answer (score 4):

I just completed the World's fair.  And I misunderstood the trophies

1. Gold is for the Highest Contributor)
2. Silver is for everyone over 350 total contribution
3. Bronze is for everyone over 175 total contribution

Now using the example below

[image: World's Fair]

In the picture is says 2800 again using this example since 2916 was contributed and you can over contribute apparently. I guess you may have to go over 50.1% theoretically as two people could contribute something like 52% each?

So to get the rewards I did get I would have only needed 1459 so I over spent by 644.64 or 44%

Lesson learned.  But will the cost be the same for each game?

**UPDATE**
[image: International Games]
Playing the same game I just learned two interesting points.

1. The total is based on the number of Starting Civs.  In the above the Zulu's and Carthridge were wiped out but the total was still 5,760 (720*8)
2. Dominating the production prevents the enemy from getting ANY bonus.

Comment: As it says in the right, "This Project requires a total of 2,800 Production" ;)

Comment: And to your other question, I believe the cost is based on size of map / game speed.

Comment: Yes I *just* saw that

Comment: Yes, that total number shows up once it is completed. :( However, the Civilopedia lists the per-civ base cost. +1 for the note that these are not 1st, 2nd, and 3rd place medals as is implied by the fact that they are gold, silver, and bronze medals.

Answer (score 1):

Hover the mouse over the icon of the World's Fair in one of the cities where you are constructing it. Then end your turn and keep hovering the mouse and as other Civs have their turn the percentage of completion of the fair will go up for each players turn. This is helpful because say if there is 10% completion from one turn to the next you can tell how muxh of that 10% you contributed and how much was from the other civs.